# Reset firefox from command line

Tags: firefox

Mozilla firefox gives an option to reset it. Check the below images to ee how its done graphically;

[image]

[image]

I need to make a script where this can be done through bash. Can someone tell me the command which can do this?

Answer (score 3):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
/usr/bin/firefox -safe-mode
```

and then click on Reset Firefox.

[image]

Addition for the latest version of Firefox:

Click on the three lines (Hamburger Menu), and then Click on Help

[image]

Click on Troubleshooting information

[image]

Click on Refresh Firefox

[image]

Comment: This is what I want to do precisely... The things that follows after pressing "Reset Firefox", is what I want to accomplish. I don't want to manually click on "Reset Firefox".

Comment: Why don't want to manually click on "Reset Firefox" if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: Because he wants to reset firefox after user logoff or daily. In both cases, it would be better to have pristine copy of .mozilla folder.

Comment: @BarafuAlbino If that's that case, then yes.

Comment: Hi Mitch, its as Barafu said.

Comment: "Refresh Firefox" ?

Comment: kubuntu 20.04 has no /usr/bin/firefox

Answer (score 1):

Just delete its folder, which is `~/.mozilla`. Beware: this will clean Thunderbird too.

Comment: I wouldn't delete the folder, better rename it: `mv ~/.mozilla ~/.mozilla_old`

Comment: Better yet: `~/.mozilla/firefox`

Comment: If I move ~/.mozilla/firefox , won't I have to again import bookmarks. The "Reset Firefox" cleans the old data and restores all saved bookmarks and preferences.

Comment: bookmarks should better be stored on sync account. Than you will enter sync credentials and get them all back.