# My Firefox 37 has problems with Yahoo mail in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, firefox

Since update to Firefox 37.0.1, I have problems with Yahoo mail (webmail).

Sometimes, inline pictures are not shown, they only end up as placeholders, also not shown as attachments. In such cases, the top indicator shows that the message should have an attachment, however it is not shown at the bottom.

In other cases, attachments are shown, but cannot download. Click on download button brings up a virus checking message, but no download.

I only saw these problems with 14.04, not with 12.04. 
In the moment, I can only use Yahoo mail with Chromium.

I already cleared cache and cookies. Other suggestions?

Comment: I dunno if it's related to Ubuntu problem rather Mozilla's you can try to refresh firefox go to menu bar--> help-->troubleshootings

Comment: same advices here http://askubuntu.com/questions/507526/reset-firefox-from-command-line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for leading me to a solution, resetting Firefox worked.

The culprit was a new setting in about:config "privacy.trackingprotection.enabled" which I had set to true.
Seems Yahoo Mail is enforcing its tracking even for paid accounts, causing such strange behaviour.